# I was denied a UK visitor visa due to not providing evidence of US residency

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I sent a copy of my permanent resident card with my application. What further evidence can I provide to re-apply? I also sent a savings account statement, pay stub, hotel, and flight reservations.

The full text of the rejection was:

The decision
I have refused your application for a visit visa because I am not satisfied that you meet the requirements of paragraph(s) V4.2 of Appendix V because:

- You have applied to visit the UK for 7 days. You state that you are currently employed by XXXX earning $XXXXUSD (£XXXX at £1 = 1.32USD – Oanda exchange rate https://www.oanda.com) a month. You state that you are also a permanent resident in the USA. From the information you have provided I have been unable to establish what permission you have to currently be in the USA. The permission you state you have to be in the USA is not reflected in the evidence you have provided.
- Given the above I am therefore not satisfied that you have demonstrated that your circumstances are as declared or are as such that you intend to leave the UK at the end of your visit. This also leads me to further doubt your intentions in travelling to the UK. Your application for a visit visa has been refused under paragraph V4.2 (a) and (c).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)

Comment: @bytebuster This situation is not covered by that question.

Comment: You have a permanent residence card but does that clearly show that you permanently reside there? How about rental agreement/mortgage docs for your residence in USA. Pay slips show you work for that company, but are you working in the USA? Perhaps these are areas you could consider?

Comment: Might be obvious, but what address did you state in the application? And where did you apply from?

Comment: I stated a US address. My pay stub and other documents all showed the same address. I did not think to provide a lease, but I thought that for a UK visa sending documents not requested might be counter-productive. At least that is the warning I see everywhere.

Comment: @canonacer Good question, but the refusal notice explicitly says "I have been unable to establish what permission you have to currently be in the USA. The permission you state you have to be in the USA is not reflected in the evidence you have provided." It seems they accept that the asker is in the US, but aren't convinced that they're there legally, for some reason. I don't see how rental agreements, pay slips, etc., would establish legality.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The permanent residency card certainly does, though.

Answer (score 3):

[The guide to supporting documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents) states clearly at the very beginning:

> All documents must be originals and not photocopies.

So I think your providing a copy of your residence permit was enough for the ECO to dismiss it as evidence of your US residency.

Both times I applied I sent in the permanent residency card together with the passport and other documents in original.

Comment: I was categorically told not to submit original documents for a visit visa.

Comment: Given the answer is from gov.uk I wonder who told you categorically that

Comment: According to [After a Green Card is Granted](https://www.uscis.gov/green-card/after-green-card-granted) "If you are a permanent resident age 18 or older, you are required to have a valid Green Card in your possession at all times."

Comment: The document checklist provided by the UK visa application web page clearly indicates "You have agreed to include this evidence with your application. Evidence can be originals or copies." I don't know of any other way to prove permanent residence than a green card.

Comment: Can you post the link to this passage?

Comment: That’s a ridiculous rule which is not followed. When I applied for UK visas I sent a photocopy without problems. This denial is just another in a long line of nonsensical visa refusals by UK ECO’s. I am not surprised.

Comment: @ThEiLlEgAlaLiEn How is it "nonsensical" to deny a visa when the instructions clearly say that original documents must be supplied and the applicant didn't do that? _Every_ refusal of a UK visa seems to be unjust in your eyes.

Comment: DavidRicherby It’s nonsensical. Why should I send off my permanent resident card for a week or more to the British Embassy when American law requires I carry it? It’s an asinine requirement by the British to think their requirements supersede USA statutes.